# Flowchart diagram assign functions value to local variable

Tags: java, algorithm, flowchart

In my scenario there are 3 functions whose values are stored in a local variables:

```
boolean var1 = someFunction1(),
        var2 = someFunction2(),
        var3 = someFunction3();
```

First I thoguht about just assigning function value like this:

[image]

But then there is no way to describe what is in the function. I would use subprocess but I don't really know how to return value from it to a local variable, or if it's even allowed.
 This is needed because I'm using those variables further in the algorithm.

**Question:** 
What would be the best approach to represent this code in a `Flowchart diagram`?

Answer (score 0):

The graph you made has a good level of generalization,
Complete would be something like this: [flow1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LgD8.png)

You can also use this "Predefined Process" reference on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart

Or if you prefer to increase information inside the same flow: [flow2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUbmY.png)

Comment: Thanks for your response. By accident I mentioned `Dataflow` not 'Flowchart' diagram, updated my question, sry.

Comment: more so, check the links on wikipedia that I advised you

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, flowcharts are a really *old fashioned* way of describing an algorithm.  IMO, they became effectively redundant when people started using programming languages<sup>1</sup> that support "structured programming"; i.e. no more `GO TO` spaghetti.

These days, you either write the code directly, or you use some kind of pseudo-code ... in your syntax of choice.  Writing code or pseudo-code is quicker than stuffing around with a diagramming tool.

However, if you are going to use flowcharts, you could use a "defined process" boxes to represent function calls.  Put the parameters and the result assignment in the box.  Then use a separate flowchart to describe what happens within the function.

For examples, take a look at [this](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/StructuredC/Chap03/struct03_16.html) or [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75895).

---

<sup>1 - About when I got my first full-time programming job in the late 1970's.</sup>